# How can I reinstall Ubuntu focal 20.04 on an existing LUKS encrypted system?

Tags: multi-boot, encryption, reinstall, luks, ubuntu-20.04

I'm a very long time Ubuntu user (over a decade) but have not been here as I've had no issues with Ubuntu. With the arrival of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I decided to encrypt my data (or system if needed). I'm looking for the following:

- Method to reinstall ubuntu with LUKS encryption on a previous LUKS encrypted Ubuntu install on a dual boot system with Windows 10.
- Keep all my personal files (ie `/home` folder) intact, with or without a separate partition. I do not wish to move everything out, reinstall and then move stuff back in.
- Simple GUI based approach through the standard installer. I know how to use the command line but I'd rather not, especially for something as sensitive as encryption.

What I'm looking for is basically [the same as this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation). Except that I need it on an LUKS encrypted system/partition. I tried doing this on a spare system with Ubuntu 20.04, and I could not find a way of telling the installer the passphrase to the encrypted system. The end result was a reinstall that wouldn't boot or the encrypted partition gets wiped out. I also tried to run installer with and without pre-unlocking the encrypted partition but to no avail.

I am able to do all of the above with Fedora, OpenSUSE, Manjaro, (although they only do this when `/home` is on separate partition, which is fine for me) so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the my personal experiments using the Ubuntu 20.04 installer, online research, and asking various forums (and lack of answers there), I conclude that as of today, there is no way to do all of the following:

- Installing/reinstalling Ubuntu ...
- using the installer GUI ...
- on a pre-encrypted system (LUKS, with separate `/home` partition or not) without destroying pre-existing personal files...
- with dual booting another OS.

Of course there are ways of doing this if you rely on the command line, which I was looking to avoid. I've decided to switch to Fedora 32 as it meets all these requirements. Ubuntu served me rather well for over a decade, hope to return when the above issue is fixed.

For those interested in my Fedora 32 setup:

- Dual-boot setup with Windows 10.
- Reuse (DO NOT FORMAT) `/boot/efi` partition from Windows 10 install
- Create UNENCRYPTED `/boot` partition
- Create/Reuse ENCRYPTED `/` partition
- Create/Reuse ENCRYPTED `/home` partition
- Provide Passphrase to unlock above encrypted partitions.
- Post install, added RPMFusion repository and Gnome Tweaks extension

Thats the summary, its been a week and so far things have been great with Fedora 32. I've not really noticed much difference from Ubuntu for my needs (Email, Browsing, viewing photos/videos, music, skype, spreadsheets, documents).

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the `autoinstall` (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1271624/58298) with `preserve: true`, but there was no success...

Comment: I have the same issue. I have an ecrypted SSD in my notebook PC with LVM. I have a separated logical volume for my /home what I want to keep but PXE based Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installer cannot manage this even after I manually opened luks volume used by the bash terminal option in the help menu at the right top. I opened luks volume containing root and home LVs but installer still doesnt show them only the luks volume as unformatted partition.

Answer (score 2):

I could manage it with my PC I had to reinstall because Ubuntu upgrade was failed from 18 LTS to 20 LTS.

I had an Ubuntu 18 LTS with two partition:

- /dev/sda1 for /boot **without** encryption
- /dev/sda5 for LVM PV **with** encryption (extended partition because Ubuntu 18 LTS installer created this way at last Christmas)

Inside the LVM partition, I have everyting encrypted with luks:

- gabor2-vg VG

  - root LV formatted for ext4 mounted for /
  - home LV formatted for ext4 mounted for /home
  - swap LV

Similarly to your case, home LV contains all my important stuff I want to keep untouched while I am reinstalling my whole system to the latest Ubutnu 20.04.1 LTS with Cinnamon UI.

I have a PXE server at home to make my job easier but you can use a USB stick as well to do the same with help of iso images and rufus image writer software.

In the first round, I tried Ubuntu 20.04 LTS net boot installer. It was started fine but showed only my partitions: sda1 and sda5, so nothing about LVM and LUKS.

I found in the help menu at the top right an option to have a bash shell. There I hope opened the LUKS volume, step back and forth but installer still not saw the LVM volumes.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 gabor2-crypt
```

As a second round, I tried exactly the same with the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS live CD as well. I opened a terminal, opened the luks container then started the installer from the desktop icon.

Magically this installer saw the LVM logical volumes if I opened the LUKS container and I could select which LV is which, and which one should be formatted and which not. Perfect, I thought but then my PC is not booted at all. I got initramfs prompt.

At the installation, when you select filesystems, mountpoints, etc for your LVM volumes, be careful with the format option to avoid accidental reformat your home LV. I reformatted /boot and / to ensure no waste remains back.

Reason was quite obvious: /etc/crypttab was not set by the installer automatically.

So I went back to the live Ubuntu CD (booted from PXE but whatever), mounted all the necessary partitions, entered into chroot, edited crypttab, regenerated initramfs and grub then I could boot while my home was remained untouched. My Cinnamon UI had the original background, icons, etc. Very nice. Would be even better if it would fully be automated :)

Here are the commands I used to fix the boot as described above. Starting point is a live Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CD on the PC we just reinstalled and want to fix.

```
# open luks container
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 gabor2-crypt

# mount LVM volumes
mount /dev/mapper/gabor2--vg-root /mnt
mount /dev/mapper/gabor2--vg-home /mnt/home
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

# mount some other thing just because to make chroot fully functional
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /run /mnt/run
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

# enter into chroot where we want to act as we would be in the properly booted target system which is our new Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
chroot /mnt

# get the UUID we have to write to /etc/crypttab file
blkid /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5: UUID="........-....-....-......." TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID=".....-.."

# create crypttab (if no vim, install it with apt!)
vim /etc/crypttab
  gabor2_crypt UUID="........-....-....-......." none luks

# regenerate initramfs and grub (initramfs might be enough but I'm lazy enough to reboot and grub update takes quite a little time)
update-initramfs -u
update-grub

# we are done, need to exit from the chroot and unmount and close everything to ensure filesystem consistency, then reboot
exit
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/run
umount /mnt/boot
umount /mnt/home
umount /mnt/
cryptsetup luksClose gabor2-crypt
reboot
```

I hope I described precise enough what I did and will help for others too.

When I just rebooted my PC without unmounting my logical volumes and without closing my LUKS container, I experienced some filesystem issues: my root volume was remounted in read-only automatically at random times. After I did that long unmount command series filesystem issue was gone.

Good luck! Have fun!

Comment: It helps to do `vgchange -a n` before `luksClose` (don't ask me why). Otherwise, it errorred for me "still in use".

Answer (score 1):

There is a Launchpad bug about this, the workaround there is:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1904270

**Workaround**

**Ubuntu 20.04: Extra Steps for Re-Using Existing LUKS Encrypted Partition**

(replace nvme0n1p8 with your encrypted LUKS partition)

- BEFORE starting the installer (if in Ubuntu or Kubuntu live CD desktop), or at the first step (if using Ubuntu Server text-based live CD installer):

```
# open existing LUKS partition 
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 nvme0n1p8_crypt
```

- Then, either do this at the end after the installer has run, or boot into a live CD environment (e.g. Kubuntu) and do:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 nvme0n1p8_crypt
mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/MainVG-root /mnt/
mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot/
mount --rbind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
mount --rbind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
mount --rbind /run/ /mnt/run/
mount --rbind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
chroot /mnt /bin/bash -l
blkid | grep crypto_LUKS
# Example: /dev/nvme0n1p8: UUID="8cb9831a-692e-4b0e-936f-72529a3ed56d" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="139f23d2-a0ff-4f4f-b41f-8083964ac894"
apt install vim
vim /etc/crypttab
# Add a line for the encrypted partiton, e.g:
# nvme0n1p8_crypt UUID="8cb9831a-692e-4b0e-936f-72529a3ed56d" none luks
#
# MAKE SURE There's a newline at end of /etc/crypttab

# update the initramfs
update-initramfs -u -k all


umount -l /mnt


# Optional, probably not needed
grub-install --recheck /dev/nvme0n1
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```